# Quantitative stability: Hausdorff distance between subdifferentials

Tags: real-analysis, convexity

Suppose I have two convex functions $f$ and $g$ mapping $\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ (so they are 'more' than proper). Suppose $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$, the sup-norm. In particular, the subdifferentials are bounded, non-empty sets (Theorem 23.4 in Rockafellar). For a given $x$, can we say anything about the Hausdorff distance between $\partial f(x)$ and $\partial g(x)$?

What I have found so far:

Attouch's Theorem proving the convergence of the subdifferentials given some convergence in the functions called epi-convergence.

On the convergence of subdifferentials of convex functions Hedy Attouch, Gerald Beer http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01207197?LI=true

On the convergence of subdifferentials of convex functions Jean-Paul Penot

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0362546X9390040Y

There is a short section on primal estimates for the convergence of subdifferentials, and although I have a hunch that this can be reformulated to include the Hausdorff distance, I'm wondering if there are any newer results that might generalize this.

Comment: Other than the Jean Paul Penot paper, nothing else seems to come up with a quantitative estimate using the Hausdorff distance.

Comment: The evident estimates seem to be optimal, but why do you need it?

Comment: I was hoping Hausdorff distance would be easier to handle; and I wanted something where there wasn't a dependence on the $r$. I think in that paper if I choose $r$ to be large enough, since $\partial f(x)$ and $\partial g(x)$ are bounded, the metric $d_{r}$ becomes the Hausdorff distance, but this isn't uniform in $x$, which is something I need.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that there is a simple bound without some other restriction. Consider $f(x) = C|x|$, i.e. $\partial f(0) = [-C,C]$. Then there is a convex $g$ with $\|f-g\|_\infty\leq\epsilon$ but $g\equiv 0$ in a neighborhood of $0$, hence $\partial g(0) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I tried looking, but would you know whether there has been some work in this area recently? I can't seem to get anything quantitative beyond the 1993 paper I linked above.

Comment: Don't know of anything, but have you checked Rockafellar and Wets' "Variational Analysis"? By the way, I suspect that the situation could be different for smooth $f$ and $g$…

Comment: You can easily modify this example to come up with smooth $f$ and $g$ with $\|f - g\|_\infty$ but $\delta f(0) = \{C\}$ and $\delta g(0) = \{-C\}$, $f$ and $g$ being translates of smoothed versions of $C |x|$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right, it's indeed simple. Well, this simply reflects that uniform convergence does not imply convergence of the derivative (although, in principle convexity could change things but apparently it doesn't).

Comment: @RobertIsrael @Dirk; Thanks for the answer and the comments. It was helpful. I think this shows that there isn't a nice Lipschitz-like bound for any two functions, but uniform convergence of convex functions does still imply convergence of the derivative -- isn't this what Theorem 25.7 in Rockafellar states?